# Creating a value list column with static choices

Tags: column, multiple-values

I’m trying to create a column in SharePoint 2010 that when one of four available answers are selected for column A, then column B will display a custom set of choices.

EX. 
If column A requires a user to select a car manufacturer, when the user selects Ford then column B will ask the user to select a sub model such as F-150, Explorer so on. If the user selected Chevy for their answer in column A then column B would have models such as Silverado and Tahoe as possibly choices.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a Filtered Drop-Down. SPServices, a free library on codeplex, has this functionality built in. Here's a link:
http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPFilterDropdown

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the info. I figured out how to get the filter columns I was wanting useing a Bamboo Lookup.

Comment: This is not really an answer. An answer should specify how you solved it, preferably with code / GUI samples